# Signal handler being called once per process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, signals

I have a program that spawns multiple processes, and I kill it with Ctrl+C.

At the start of the program I trap the signal in order to execute some cleanup operations.

```
def cleanup(*_):
    # do cleanup operations here
    # ...
    exit(1)

# trap ctrl+c and hide the traceback message
signal(SIGINT, cleanup)

# spawn processes (pool of workers) and do work here
# ...
```

The problem is that `cleanup` is being called multiple times (once per each running process).

How can I make it so `cleanup` is only called once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child processes are inheriting the signal handler from their parent. If you want the handler to execute in only one process, you might wanna deregister the handler in the child processes.

Comment: How do I unregister it? I'm guessing there's another way besides pointing it to a handler of an empty function?

Comment: original_sigint_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)
Then, later...
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_sigint_handler)